# Default media uploader is not showing in wordpress website

Tags: plugin-development, media, plugin-wpml

There is a custom post type events in the website. When I create a new post under events i am facing issue with media uploader

When i tried to upload the featured images in the english version of the website, it works properly.

But when i tried to upload the featured images in the arabic version of the website, the attached media uploader is shown.

[image]

How to get back the default wordpress media uploader?

Comment: Does the "Switch to the multi-file uploader" link work?

Comment: @Rup No, it shows the same type of screen